# Black screen in Google Map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

when I'm refreshing content of `GoogleMap` sometimes it blinks with black screen and then load `map`.

```
 GoogleMap(
                      // markers: getMarkers(),
                      myLocationEnabled: false,
                      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                      mapType: MapType.normal,
                      initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                        getCurrentLocation();
                        googleMapController = controller;
                        // mapController.complete(controller);
                      },
                      onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPositions) {
                        cameraPosition = cameraPositions; //when map is
                      },
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 50),
                      onCameraIdle: _getAddress,
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

yes sir. I also found that when I worked with GoogleMap package. what you need to do is show a widget until map fully appears

```
bool isMapLoading = true


GoogleMap(
  myLocationEnabled: false,
  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
  mapType: MapType.normal,
  initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
  setState(() => isMapLoading = false),//here
  getCurrentLocation();
  googleMapController = controller;
  // mapController.complete(controller);
  },
  onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPositions) {
      cameraPosition = cameraPositions; //when map is
   },
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 50),
    onCameraIdle: _getAddress,
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(37.4220, -122.0841),
      zoom: 15,
    ),
  
  (isMapLoading )
      ? Container(
          height: size.height,
          width: size.width,
          color: Colors.grey[100],
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        )
      : Container(),
```

Comment: Yes this is one of the solution but I can't do this in my project because I'm not having simple map i'm performing socket.io operation to get markers in map and moreover my whole app is based on map. If something went wrong with this then purpose of my app can completely wiped away.

Is there any other solution? Because i already tried this before.

Comment: I checked and they resolve it with Hybrid Composition.  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93335